# Asp.Net Core + Angular: NodeInvocationException: Prerendering timed out after 30000ms because the boot function in 'ClientApp/dist/main-server'

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm getting the following server error from an ASP.NET Core website that was created using an angular project template.

`NodeInvocationException: Prerendering timed out after 30000ms because the boot function in 'ClientApp/dist/main-server' returned a promise that did not resolve or reject. Make sure that your boot function always resolves or rejects its promise. You can change the timeout value using the 'asp-prerender-timeout' tag helper.`

This error goes away if I delete `dealService.getDeals()` in `deal.component.ts`
How do I resolve this issue without removing the call to `getDeals()`?

**file: deal.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DealService } from './deal.service'
import { Deal } from './deal'

@Component({
    selector: 'deal',
    templateUrl: './deal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./deal.component.css']
})
export class DealComponent {
    deals: Deal[] = [
        { title: 'Title #1', desc: 'Desc #1' },
        { title: 'Title #2', desc: 'Desc #2' }
    ];
    constructor(private dealService: DealService) {    
        dealService.getDeals();
    }
```

**file: deal.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { List } from 'immutable';
import { Deal } from './deal'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
@Injectable()
export class DealService {

    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {        
    }

    getDeals(): Promise<Deal[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "api/Deal/All")
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Deal[])
            .catch(this.handleError);        
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a solution. I mistyped the HTTP endpoint and it should have been "api/Deals/All" and not "api/Deal/All".

Though, I really don't like error message that was reported by ASP.NET as it's not clear as to what went wrong. Debugging a similar bug in a large production application would have been like finding a needle in a hay stack.

Comment: You seem like a seasoned developer in microsoft land.  I'm surprised you aren't you used to cryptic error messages :P.  Congrats on the find though.